# Is there a way of listing all tests in a Cargo project without running them?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Waiting for a large test suite to run is painful, so I collect the duration of each test from `cargo test` and use a simple heuristic to find failures fast (I order by probability of failure/last run duration and run tests in that order).

This is great, but it doesn't have a way of knowing about new tests.  If I could list all tests, I could detect new tests and add them to the high risk group that gets run first.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can run `cargo test -- --list` to list all tests and benchmarks. The output format is:

```
glonk: benchmark
hurz: test

1 test, 1 benchmark
```

You can suppress the summary line by passing the `--format=terse` flag.

Note that `--list` is a command line flag that is passed to the test binary itself, and not a Cargo flag. You can get a full list of flags accepted by the test binary using `cargo test -- --help`.

Comment: Thank you.  I also looked at the `--format json` option; that is unstable and doesn't work.  Hopefully it will, but that is not a big problem.  The text format is easy to parse and has all the data I need. :-)

Comment: Here is the updated script: https://gist.github.com/bitdivine/b785e6062d6fbf1becc69b78b8f6351f